# Data not written with ofstream, even though success is returned

Tags: c++, ofstream

I'm writing a program which fetches a large number of email files using libcurl and then writes the file to disk, and then generates a receipt.

My problem is that, whilst most of the receipts seem to get written, the majority of the emails aren't written to disk.  Worse, even though the file doesn't get written, ofstream returns success - so the receipt gets written even if the file write didn't complete successfully.

My guess is that, because ofstream is asynchronous, if a write doesn't complete in time then it'll get dropped on the floor - only a certain number of writes being possible concurrently.  I am just guessing here.
Perhaps I need to refactor my code to write synchronously - but I can't believe that that's necessary.  Does anyone have any idea how I can make this work?

The email sizes range from a few KBytes to a couple of MBytes.

```
int write_file(string filename, string mail_item) {
    ofstream out(filename.c_str());
    out << mail_item;
    out.close();
    out.flush();
    if (!out) {
        return FUNCTION_FAILED;
    }
    return FUNCTION_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

This is part of another function, and has been cut out so that only the salient code for this question is shown.

```
vector<string> directory = curl_listroot(curl);      

for (int i=0; i<directory.size(); i++) {
    vector<int> mail_list = curl_search(curl,directory[i],make_vector<string>() << "SEEN" << "RECENT" << "NEW" << "ANSWERED" << "FLAGGED");
    for (int j=0; j<mail_list.size(); j++) {
        curl_reset(curl, imap.username, imap.password);
        string mail_item = curl_fetch(curl,directory[i],mail_list[j]);
        if (mail_item.compare("") != 0) {
            string m_id = getMessageID(mail_item);
            string filename = save_path+"/"+RECEIPTNAME+"/"+clean_filename(m_id) + ".eml";
            if (!file_exists(filename)) {
                string real_filename;
                real_filename = save_path+"/"+INBOXNAME+"/"+clean_filename(m_id) + ".eml";
                int success = write_file(real_filename, mail_item);
                if (success == FUNCTION_SUCCESS) {
                    write_file(filename, ""); //write empty receipt
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

All suggestions gratefully received!  Thank you!

Comment: Try checking the status of the stream after you open it. And after you write. And after you close. You don't need to do it after the flush, because you don't need the flush (the stream buffer will be flushed as part of closing).

Comment: Something is not right with the code you pasted.... `int write_file(string filename, string mail_item) {` is a function declaration and right after it is a `for` loop.

Comment: Why not putting `if (!out) {` immediately after `out << mail_item;`?

Comment: @Alex It's a _function definition_ to be precise, but yes.

Comment: Make sure that there's a newline (`'\n'`) at the end of your output. It probably won't help, but technically it's required.

Comment: My apologies - I should have been explicit in that this code won't run as is - the function is complete, but the code below is part of another function.

Comment: `m_id = getMessageID(mail_item);` - may it collide sometimes? `int write_file(string filename, string mail_item)` rather use const references, to avoid any copy constructors, if some mail has MB size, it may fail on copy, i.e.: `int write_file(const string & filename, const string & mail_item)`. Overall it feels a bit too elegant, like missing some more error state checks. If all the functions throw proper exceptions, or propagate earlier error further, it may be ok, but rather verify in debugger by simulating failures at each stage.

Comment: If I remove the writes to the real file and just write the receipts, they all get written - demonstrating that there are no collisions with getMessageID. Nice idea though.

Comment: Think on the writes themselves - the receipt should only be written if the actual mail file itself has been written successfully. Sadly, the receipts seem to get written regardless of whether or not the actual mail file was written successfully. Mostly, anyway.

Comment: Remove both the `close()` and the `flush()` lines. They're unnecessary. `close` already flushes before closing the file (flushing is meaningless afterwards) and the destructor closes the file.

Comment: "because ofstream is asynchronous" – no, it's not. Learning by guessing isn't very effective.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I've found an answer - there may be better answers - but this one works for me.  The problem seems to be in the OS (Linux, in this case) - ofstream completes, having handed the responsibility for writing the file to the OS, but the file hasn't actually been written yet (so whilst ofstream may be synchronous the end to end write of the file, from data to file safely written to disk, isn't).  Given that I'm banging away with a huge number of writes in quick succession (potentially thousands), this won't necessarily work.  The OS may throw its hands in the air and drop a significant number of the files writes on the floor (hence my original request for a synchronous way of writing the files - end to end).

My solution is to pause after each write to give the OS time to catch up.  It's inelegant though, and not as performant as it should be - it doesn't take half a second to write an empty file.  Additionally, on slow storage, half a second might not be enough time.  I'd welcome any clever suggestions for how to improve my code.

```
int write_file(string filename, string mail_item) {
    ofstream out(filename.c_str());
    if (!out) {
        return FUNCTION_FAILED;
    }
    out << mail_item << endl;
    out.flush();
    usleep(500000); //wait for half a second to give the OS time to output the file
    if (!out) {
        return FUNCTION_FAILED;
    }
    out.close();
    if (!out) {
        return FUNCTION_FAILED;
    }
    return FUNCTION_SUCCESS;
}
```